# Excel - Deduction in multiple cells

Tags: excel, count, sum

I tried to find solution for this tricky thing, but I was not very successful. I would like to ask you for a help.

I have a four numbers

```
A=5
B=3
C=9
```

and another cell D=10

I need to find solution for deduction of number D from other cells until that cells equal 0 and than deduct from another cell to 0 until the cell D is 0 too.

After deduction should be

```
A=0
B=0
C=7
```

and

```
D=0
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Kindest regards,

Testovka

Comment: With formulas this can not be done in the same cells as the starting numbers, You will need vba for that.

Comment: Is it not possible also with helper rows?

Comment: I did not say that I said if you want the change in the same cells as the original values then you would need vba.  If you want the results in the cells below then yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two formulas:

In A2 put:

```
=MAX(SUM($A$1:A$1)-$D$1,0)
```

And copy/fill to C2.

Then in D2 put:

```
=MAX($D$1-SUM($A$1:$C$1),0)
```

[image]

Comment: You are awsome! Thank you very much.